# Сгенерировать 2а случайных двузначных числа в JS и в их диапазоне сгенирировать ещё 3и любых

Tags: javascript

С генерацией есть представление, а как в этом диапазоне ещё 3 числа создать не понимаю. Желательно без использования funtion. Возможно через цикл for,но как реализовать нужна помощь. При использовании Math.random в for не будет понятно какая из переменных будет большая , какая меньшая. В Math.random необходимо знать какая min и max.

```
let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как-то так мб.

```js
const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;  

const a = getRandom(0, 999);  
const b = getRandom(0, 999); 
 
const numX = getRandom(a, b); 
const numY = getRandom(a, b); 
const numZ = getRandom(a, b); 

console.log(`${numX} ${numY} ${numZ}`);
```

Ну или так.

```js
const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

const getLastRandom = (min, max) => {
  const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  return [a, b];
};

const [a, b] = getLastRandom(0, 100);

const getNums = (a, b) => {
  if (a > b) {
    return {
      numX: getRandom(b, a),
      numY: getRandom(b, a),
      numZ: getRandom(b, a),
    };
  } else {
    return {
      numX: getRandom(a, b),
      numY: getRandom(a, b),
      numZ: getRandom(a, b),
    };
  }
};

const number = getNums(a, b);
console.log(number);
```

Немного автоматизации.

```js
const getNums = (a, b) => {
  const objNum = {
    numX: null,
    numY: null,
    numZ: null,
  };

  let result = null;
  for (const key in objNum) {
    if (a > b) {
      objNum[key] = getRandom(b, a);
      result = objNum;
    } else {
      objNum[key] = getRandom(b, a);
      result = objNum;
    }
  }
  return result; 
};
```

Comment: Благодарю. Без стрелочных функций возможно ли это сделать. В общем без функций

Comment: Немного улучшил пример - с проверкой сделал. Ну можно и без функций, но не нужно их бояться, без функций больно.

Comment: Немного топорно вышло, нарушаю правило "не повторяйся" за-то быстро)))

Comment: Согласен)). Но задача состояла в том чтоб решить без функции. Возможно с дублированием кода что не очень чисто конечно.

Comment: Дублирования убрал, без функций вы не сможете выносить результаты за предел  блока, это некая передача между, иными словами мост.  Никто не мешает это сделать без функций, но тогда будет дублирования и все будет в глобальной области.  Да и код читать сложнее.

Comment: благодарю за разъяснения

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял, что нужно, то общая формула для линейного распределения выглядит так:

```
let value = min + (max - min) * Math.random()
```

Comment: Если вы про общую для трех цифр в диапазоне между случайными let a,b то наверное нет так как не известно какая из переменных будет min какая max

Comment: ну так вы сначала получили `a,b` и теперь получаете значение где `min(a, b)`, `max(a, b)`